# Minha função JavaScript/AJAX não está convertendo Date no formato correto

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, .net, mvc

Olá

Estou com um problema num projeto MVC. Minha View precisa retornar valores em Data para alguns Text Boxes (a partir da seleção do registro por uma Data Table) para que o usuário possa fazer o edit do registro.

O problema é que os dados não estão sendo mostrados no formato correto. As TextBoxes mostram Strings estranhas como essa no lugar:

> /Date(1515290400000)/

Minha função JavaScript está assim:

```
function GetDepSecById(DepartmentSectionId) {
$.ajax({
    url: urlGetDepSecById,
    data: { DepartmentSectionId: DepartmentSectionId },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) {

        $('#DepartmentSectionId').val(result.DepartmentSectionId);
        $('#ObsoleteDate').val(result.ObsoleteDate);
        $('#StartPeriodDate').val(result.StartPeriodDate);
        $('#EndPeriodDate').val(result.EndPeriodDate);

        DatePickerPadrao($('#ObsoleteDate'));
        DatePickerPadrao($('#StartPeriodDate'));
        DatePickerPadrao($('#EndPeriodDate'));
    }
  });
}
```

O método DataPickerPadrao é o que deveria ser responsável por converter a Data. Ele está dentro de outro JS no projeto:

```
function DatePickerPadrao(control) {
control.datetimepicker(
{
    locale: 'en-US',
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
});
}
```

Comment: Pode mostrar um exemplo de como chega a data em `result.ObsoleteDate`?

Comment: No Script da Controller deste método JsonResult GetDepSecById, a ObsoleteDate retorna o dado {11/07/2018 13:35:26}. No entanto, na TextBox da View onde esse valor é jogado é mostrada esta string: /Date(1531326926000)/

Answer (score 1):

Basta você pegar o retorno e converter para data usando `parseInt`. Antes remova as barras. Veja um exemplo:

```js
var retorno = "/Date(1531326926000)/";
// remove as barras com o Regex, ou pode ser um replace também
retorno = retorno.replace(/[^0-9 +]/g, ''); 
// converte o formato numérico para data
var data = new Date(parseInt(retorno));
console.log(data);

//se quiser no formato texto:
console.log(data.getDate() + "/" + (data.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + data.getFullYear());
```

Uma sugestão para trabalhar com datas é usar o `moment.js`, que tem métodos para formatar e converter, simples de usar: [http://momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/)

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo! Tanto sua solução quanto usando por moment.js